# Allow only alphanumeric character

Tags: asp.net

i want to allow only alphanumeric password i have written following code to match the same
but the same is not working

> Regex.IsMatch(txtpassword.Text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$") never return false
>   even if i type password test(which do not contain any number).

```
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(txtpassword.Text, "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$") = False Then
 div_msg.Attributes.Add("class", "err-msg")
 lblmsg.Text = "password is incorrect"

I have tried this also
Dim r As New Regex("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$")
Dim bool As Boolean
bool = r.IsMatch(txtpassword.Text) and for txtpassword.Text = '4444' , bool is coming true i dont know what is wrong.
```

Comment: are you working on windows or web application.......

Comment: what is the value of `txtpassword.Text` when you debug?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910063/allow-only-alphanumeric-in-textbox

may be this can help you little.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the '_' is not a valid alpha-numeric character.
See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric

And, second, take another look at your regular expression.

[a-zA-Z0-9_]*

This can match 0 OR more alpha-numeric characters or 0 OR more '_' characters.
Using this pattern, a password '&#&#^$' would return TRUE.

You probably want to test for 1 OR more characters that ARE NOT an alpha-numeric. If that test returns TRUE, then throw the error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following Expression:

```
([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

This will match if your Password contains any character that is not alphanumeric.
If you get a match, do your error handling.

Comment: hi, i tried the following code  If Regex.IsMatch(txtpassword.Text, "([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)") = False Then
div_msg.Attributes.Add("class", "err-msg")
lblmsg.Text = "password is incorrect" but for password 455tt it is still not working

Comment: If the IsMatch  of this Pattern returns False, that means no invalid characters are found. So basically you're now saying "password is incorrect" only when the password is valid...
Just remove the "= False" and you will be fine

Answer (score 1):

So based on the Regex that you have in the question, it *appears* you want a password with one lower-case and upper-case letter, one number, and an `_`; so here is a Regex that will do that:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*_).{4,8}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1gUrmZsOg0Wfch3P)

The `{4,8}` indicates the length of the password; you can set that accordingly.