# Limit acceptable characters in a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'd like to have a textbox behave such that only alphanumeric characters can be entered & added to `.Text`. If a non-alphanumeric key is pressed while focus is in the textbox, I simply want the key press thrown out.

I tried the following:

```
private static Regex alphaNumericOnly = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$");

private void txtJustification_KeyDown(object sender, KeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (!alphaNumericOnly.IsMatch(e.KeyValue.ToString()))
        e.Handled = true;
}
```

But this did not work. I also tried the `_KeyDownPreview` and `_KeyPress` events, but the entered non-alphanumeric character still appears in the textbox.

Comment: You could try using a `MaskedTextBox`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx

Comment: You should better handle `TextChanged` because the user could paste text into the TextBox

Answer (score 1):

I think you better do this in the TextChanged event, because a user might try to copy/paste other characters.
Also you do not want the keydown to block the user from using the arrow keys, and the delete key, and the back key, and so on...

```
private void txtJustification_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var cursorPosition = txtJustification.SelectionStart;
    txtJustification.Text = Regex.Replace(txtJustification.Text, "[^0-9a-zA-Z ]", "");
    txtJustification.SelectionStart = cursorPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because KeyCode is of type Keys which is an enum telling you which key is down, not the actual char (so a '+' char would be Keys.Add, thus your regex would never work properly).

What you can do is either:

- Drop the Regex and work with the KeyCode (example:
  [Allow only alphanumeric in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910063/allow-only-alphanumeric-in-textbox))
- Use the TextChanged event and keep the Regex (see GuidoG's answer).